# Convert year only to Datetime in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I'm currently using an API which returns dates. These dates are never of the same format. For example; I sometimes get a date like 1987/10/12 or sometimes it just returns the year.

I tried to convert this date to a format I can import into my mysql database but it always autocompletes the date with the current timestamp.

```
$item['released'] = "1989";
var_dump(strtotime($item['released']));
```

This would return Thu, 23 Nov 1989 11:53:53 GMT (added day/month/year and time for current timestamp with the correct year)

Why is this and how can I tell that it has to be something like 1989/01/01 00:00:00
Or should I look at this in another way?

Thanks

Comment: [mktime()](http://www.php.net/function.mktime)

Comment: "These dates are never of the same format." Why don't you post typical examples of what these dates are then. Also, 1987/10/12  - is that 12 October or 10 December?

Comment: i just doesn't return the month or day when it's not available. It in american format btw

Comment: What kind of API returns random date formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and comment ("i just doesn't return the month or day when it's not available. It in american format btw") I would assume, possible dates you get are:

- 1987/12/10
- 1987/12
- 1987

Correct?

If so, you could use something like:

```
    $arr = explode('/', $input);
    $modifiedInput = $arr[0] . '/' .
            ((isset($arr[1])) ? $arr[1] : '01') . '/' .
            ((isset($arr[2])) ? $arr[2] : '01') . 
            ' 00:00:00';
```

$modifiedInput would be '1987/12/10 00:00:00' for the 1st possible input, '1987/12/01 00:00:00' for the 2nd, '1987/01/01 00:00:00' for the 3rd.

IF the API might return trailing slashes (e.g. '1987/12/'), you will need to modify the condition in the ternary operators...

Comment: Nicer example would be to use `sscanf()` function like **[this demo](https://eval.in/72800)**.